# how do I put a dot in a \fmf line using feynmp?

Tags: feynmf, feynmp

[image]

I would like to add a dot to the top of the circle, but `\fmfdot` only works on vertices. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\begin{document}
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{fmffile}{interaction}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,20)
    \fmfstraight
    \fmftop{i1,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,o1}
    \fmfbottom{i2,b1,o2}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=0}{i1,t4}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=0}{t4,o1}
    \fmf{phantom}{i2,b1,o2}
    \fmf{photon,tension=0}{t4,b1}
    \fmflabel{$p$}{t2}
    \fmflabel{$p'$}{t6}      
    \fmf{plain,right}{t3,t5}
   \fmf{plain,left}{t3,t5}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I just post the code of the graph.

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,20)
\fmfipath{p[]}
\fmfipair{vv[]}
\fmfstraight
\fmftop{i1,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,o1}
\fmfbottom{i2,b1,o2}
\fmf{fermion,tension=0}{i1,t4}
\fmf{fermion,tension=0}{t4,o1}
\fmf{phantom}{i2,b1,o2}
\fmf{photon,tension=0}{t4,b1}
\fmflabel{$p$}{t2}
\fmflabel{$p'$}{t6}      
\fmf{plain,right}{t3,t5}
\fmf{plain,left}{t3,t5}
\fmfiset{p1}{vpath(__t3,__t5)}
\fmfiset{vv1}{point length(p1)/2 of p1}
\fmfiv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick}{vv1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

[image]

Comment: Except for the \end{fmfgraph*} typo in the middle this is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @ScienceGuy : Sorry for the typo, fixed it.